# How to allocate work fairly when scaling out my scheduling service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I want to auto-scale a Spring Boot service in Kubernetes cluster, but the service performs some scheduled work.

Is it possible to synchronize instances somehow to let them split time fairly between instances?

Comment: you can tried to add a distribution lock with your schedule task to avoid run multi task in the same time @J.J. Beam

Comment: idk if spring scheduler supports that. how about using quartz scheduler?

Comment: @Dolphin what kind of `distribution lock` do you mean? Some Ready-made solution?

Comment: what kind of schedule task you are running? if you want to run the task in the same time,you should tried to seperate the resource, or run one task in one node in the same time. it should by your bizeness logic to decide how to handle it.@J.J. Beam

Comment: You should tried show more details about your logic.@J.J. Beam

Comment: Ok, I see it's not a `Ready-made solution` right? So the `distribution lock` you mention is some custom lock implementation?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, the distribution lock would avoid run task in the same time dulpicate when you using mullti pod in kubernetes @J.J. Beam

Comment: I only asked: is `distribution lock` something made in kubernetes out of the box or need to implement all `distribution lock's` logic by myself? ( for example I ask: is the `synchronized` feature available in java out of the box or do I need to implement `synchronization` by myself? --- !don't please answer on this, I know the answer!)